# Center line based on part of text while the relative position of the rest doesn't change

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
{\hspace*{0.5em}
\vfill
\begin{center}
left left \- | \- right
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]
I would like to make `|` to be centered, which is not according to the page number, and the relative position of the rest text doesn't change.

I don't see a way to do this, [Center line based on only part of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75088/center-line-based-on-only-part-of-text) suggests `\parbox` but it would ignore the relative position of the line.

Comment: Perhaps `\makebox[0pt][r]{left left \ }|\makebox[0pt][l]{ \ right}`?  BTW, what are the `\-` meant for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.



\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    \makebox[0pt][r]{left left left \ }|\makebox[0pt][l]{ \ right}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\-` denotes a “discretionary hyphen”, *not* some kind of horizontal space.